# Reproject map without resampling

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, c++

[image: QGIS]

I am going to build my on On-The-Fly projection system, just like QGIS's. A re there any C++ Libraries that will allow this?

QGIS does not to resample the raster while on-the-fly reprojection, but to distort the image.

Didn't figure out how QGIS do this after read the source code.

Comment: Welcome to the GIS SE. Could you please clarify what you are asking? Are you looking to create your on on-the-fly projection system? Or are you looking to stop the rasters being resampled on projecting them?

Comment: I am going to build my own otf projection system.

Comment: PROJ.4 https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4 used by GDAL http://www.gdal.org/ both have C++ libs and headers. Good luck with that!

Comment: If you stick with conformal projections, you can try to minimize the resampling but different coordinate systems distort the data differently--you have to resample rasters or the data won't be displayed correctly.